# How can I git clone using http?

Tags: git, clone

The caveat being that my bare repo is in the home directory - i.e. it is in ~/root.git.

I'm using this [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository).

I tried

```
git clone http://www.domain.com/root.git
```

but this does not work b.c. my domain points to a folder called `public_html` which is at the same level in the folder hierarchy as `root.git`

```
fatal: repository not found
```

is the error.

Is there any way to have it look up one directory.  I tried

```
git clone http://www.domain.com/../root.git
```

Comment: what do you expect us to do ?

Comment: Perhaps point your domain at `~/` instead of `public_html`?

Comment: If it is outside your `public_html` folder then it is not supposed to be accessible over HTTP. You could create symlink to the folder, but that would make it accessible to anyone. Do you have SSH access?

Comment: My host provider does not give me access to do this unfortunately.  It should be simple to modify `.htaccess` to do this but I'm not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible to access anything over HTTP if the HTTP server is not configured to serve it.

Since your file is above the document root then, unless you introduce aliases / rewrites / etc to expose it, it is inaccessible.

Comment: How can I setup an alias to expose it?

Comment: Depends on which web server software you use. Searching its manual for the word "alias" will probably tell you (as would combining it's name and that word in a [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=apache+httpd+alias&ia=qa)).

Comment: I use aliases in bash scripts, but I don't see the relevance here ?

Comment: Web server aliases and Bash aliases are different kinds of alias and are unrelated beyond having the same root in the English language. (Hence the recommendation to check the manual for your web server and not for bash).